# Receive error exception using xampp with wordpress

Tags: xml

I have this php function in xampp server using php 5.5, using a live server with php 5.3 I get no error. The error says

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpresstest\wp-content\plugins\Monetizer_Pro_Monetizer\Monetizer.php:910
>   Stack trace:
>    #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpresstest\wp-content\plugins\Monetizer_Pro_Monetizer\Monetizer.php(910): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('')
>    #1 [internal function]: Monetizer->Commission_Junction(Array, '', 'Commission Junc...')
>    #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpresstest\wp-includes\shortcodes.php(273): call_user_func(Array, Array, '', 'Commission Junc...')
>    #3 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag(Array)
>    #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpresstest\wp-includes\shortcodes.php(188): preg_replace_callback('/[([?)(embed|...', 'do_shortcode_ta...', '[Amazon keyword...')
>    #5 [internal function]: do_shortcode('[Amazon keyword...')
>    #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpresstest\wp-includes\plugin.php(199): call_user_func_array('do_shortcode', Array)
>    #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpresstest\wp-includes\post-template.php(166): apply_filters('the_content', '[Amazon keyword...')
>    #8 C:\xampp in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpresstest\wp-content\plugins\Monetizer_Pro_Monetizer\Monetizer.php on line 910

The function is

```
public function Commission_Junction($atts) {
            extract( shortcode_atts( array(
                'keyword' => '',
                'results' => '',
                'context' => '',
            ), $atts ) );

            $params = shortcode_atts(array(
                'keyword' => '',
                'results' => '',
                'context' => '',
            ), $atts);
            if ($params['context'] !== 'yes') {
                $linkcloakeroptions = get_option('LinkCloaker_Settings');
                $linkcloakerpath = $linkcloakeroptions['Main_Path'];
                if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$linkcloakerpath.'/Monetizer_Pro_LinkCloaker/LinkCloaker.php')) {
                    $LinkCloaker = new LinkCloaker();
                    $LinkCloakerexist = true;
                    $arv = $LinkCloaker->getFirstAvailablePage();
                    $linkpage = $arv[0];
                    $folder = $arv[1]; 
                    $linkpage = $LinkCloaker->createPage($linkpage, $folder);
                }
            }
            $contextuallinkoptions = get_option('ContextualLink_Settings');
            $contextuallinkpath = $contextuallinkoptions['Main_Path'];
            if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$contextuallinkpath.'/Monetizer_Pro_ContextualLink/ContextualLink.php')) {
                $ContextualLink = new ContextualLink();
            }
            if ($params['context'] == "yes") {
                return $ContextualLink->start("Commission_Junction", $params['results']);
            }
            else {
                $options = get_option('Monetizer_Settings');
                $monetizerpath = $options['Main_Path'];
                $cloak = $options['Commission_Junction_Link_Check'];
                $cDevKey = $options['Commission_Junction_API_Key'];
                $nWebSiteID = $options['Commission_Junction_Site_ID'];
                $cURL = 'https://product-search.api.cj.com/v2/product-search?';
                $cURL .= 'website-id=' . $nWebSiteID;
                $cURL .= '&keywords=' . $params['keyword'];
                $cURL .= '&records-per-page=' . $params['results'];
                $cURL .= '&page-number=' . '1';
                $cURL .= '&advertiser-ids=' . $options['Commission_Junction_Advertiser_Relationship'] . '&';
                $cURL .= '&serviceable-area=' . $options['Commission_Junction_Country'];
                if ($options['Commission_Junction_Low_Price'] != '') {
                    $cURL .= '&low-price=' . $options['Commission_Junction_Low_Price'];
                }
                if ($options['Commission_junction_High_price'] != '') {
                   $cURL .= '&high-price=' . $options['Commission_junction_High_price']; 
                }

                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $cURL);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                              'Authorization: ' . $cDevKey,
                              'User-Agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.15) Gecko/2009101601 Firefox/3.0.15 GTB6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"'
                            ));

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

                $response = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch); 

                //$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
                $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
                if ($LinkCloakerexist) {
                    $linknumber = 0;
                }
                foreach ($xml->products->product as $item) {
                    echo $item;
                }
                if ($xml) {
                    if (isset($options['Commission_Junction_Products_Display_Heading'])) {
                        $product .= "<h3>".$options['Commission_Junction_Products_Display_Heading']."</h3><br />";
                    }
                    $template = $options['Commission_Junction_Post_Template'];
                   foreach ($xml->products->product as $item) {
                        if ($options['User_Level'] == 'basic') {
                            $this_row = '<div style="display:table-row-group;width:'.$options['Commission_Junction_Post_Width'].'px;"><a href=%link%><img width="150px" height="150px" src=%imgURL%></a><p style="float:right;width:'.($options['Commission_Junction_Post_Width']-200).'px;text-align:left;"><a href=%link% class="Commission_Junction_Post_A">%title%<br /><span class="Commission_Junction_Post_Font">%price%</span> from %merchantname%</a><br /><span class="Commission_Junction_Post_Font">%description%</span></p></div>';
                        }
                        else if ($options['User_Level'] == 'advanced') {
                            $this_row = $template;
                        }

                        $link  = $item->xpath('buy-url');
                        $link  = (string)$link[0];
                        if ($LinkCloakerexist && $cloak == true) {
                            $LinkCloaker = new LinkCloaker();
                            $arv = $LinkCloaker->createCloakedLink($link, $linknumber, $linkpage, $folder, false, $options['Commission_Junction_Auto_Generated']);  // link complete with your aff ID

                            $link = $arv[0];
                            $linknumber = $arv[1];
                            $linknumber++;
                        }
                        else {
                            $link = $link;
                        }

                        $title = $item->xpath('name');
                        $title = (string)$title[0];

                        $imgURL = $item->xpath('image-url');
                        $imgURL = (string)$imgURL[0];

                        if ($imgURL == '') {
                            $imgURL = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$monetizerpath.'/Monetizer_Pro_Monetizer/images/noimage.png';
                        }
                        else {
                            $imgURL = $imgURL;
                        }

                        $price = $item->xpath('price');
                        $price = '$'.number_format((float)$price[0],2,'.',',');

                        $merchantname = $item->xpath('advertiser-name');
                        $merchantname = (string)$merchantname[0];

                        $description = $item->xpath('description');
                        $description = (string)$description[0];

                        $adid = $item->xpath('ad-id');
                        $adid = (string)$adid[0];

                        $advertiserid = $item->xpath('advertiser-id');
                        $advertiserid = (string)$advertiserid[0];

                        $advertisername = $item->xpath('advertiser-name');
                        $advertisername = (string)$advertisername[0];

                        $advertisercategory = $item->xpath('advertiser-category');
                        $advertisercategory = (string)$advertisercategory[0];

                        $catalogid = $item->xpath('catalog-id');
                        $catalogid = (string)$catalogid[0];

                        $currency = $item->xpath('currency');
                        $currency = (string)$currency[0];

                        $instock = $item->xpath('in-stock');
                        $instock = (string)$instock[0];

                        $isbn = $item->xpath('isbn');
                        $isbn = (string)$isbn[0];

                        $manufacturername = $item->xpath('manufacturer-name');
                        $manufacturername = (string)$manufacturername[0];

                        $manufacturersku = $item->xpath('manufacturer-sku');
                        $manufacturersku = (string)$manufacturersku[0];

                        $retailprice = $item->xpath('retail-price');
                        $retailprice = (string)$retailprice[0];

                        $saleprice = $item->xpath('sale-price');
                        $saleprice = (string)$saleprice[0];

                        $sku = $item->xpath('sku');
                        $sku = (string)$sku[0];

                        $upc = $item->xpath('upc');
                        $upc = (string)$upc[0];
                        $replace_array = array(
                                '%link%' => $link,
                                '%title%' => $title,
                                '%imgURL%' => $imgURL,
                                '%price%' => $price,
                                '%merchantname%' => $merchantname,
                                '%description%' => $this->DescriptionLength($description),
                                '%adid%' => $adid,
                                '%advertiserid%' => $advertiserid,
                                '%advertisername%' => $advertisername,
                                '%advertisercategory%' => $advertisercategory,
                                '%catalogid%' => $catalogid,
                                '%currency%' => $currency,
                                '%instock%' => $instock,
                                '%isbn%' => $isbn,
                                '%manufacturername%' => $manufacturername,
                                '%manufacturersku%' => $manufacturersku,
                                '%retailprice%' => $retailprice,
                                '%saleprice%' => $saleprice,
                                '%sku%' => $sku,
                                '%upc%' => $upc,
                            );
                            foreach($replace_array as $search => $replace) {
                                $this_row = str_replace($search, $replace, $this_row);
                            }

                        if($link != "") {
                            $product .= $this_row;
                        }
                   }

                    if ($product == '') { 
                    }
                    if ($cloak == true) {
                        $LinkCloaker->createCloakedLink($link, $linknumber, $linkpage, $folder, true, $options['Commission_Junction_Auto_Generated']);
                    }
                    return $product;
                }
            }
        }
```

Why do I receive this error? And what do I do to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Ask the author of the Monetizer_Pro_Monetizer plugin, it's their code.

Comment: i am the author

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrew:

As already mentioned, your curl call seems to be returning FALSE.  It also appears than when you try to create a SimpleXML element with a boolean FALSE that it throws the exception you are seeing.  I have also had problems accessing APIs via curl when on my localhost.   I was able to solve it by adding this code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 2);
```

Also try adding this, although for my script it was not necessary:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );

Comment: Fixing an uncaught Exception with a message of `'String could not be parsed as XML' ` tells me that it has *nothing* to do with cURL. Anyway, please file an [edit] and explain why you think this would help.

Comment: that solved the problem and loads the products properly, did not have to add curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 ) thanks

Answer (score 2):

I tried to run your code. The first trivial guess is that the curl operation

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

return false. May are many reasons for this! timeout, wrong call, wrong authkey, ... and this is why the

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
```

returns an error!
Simly check the value of $response before try to xml parse it.

Comment: thank you i can test it, i think i may know what is causing the problem, after a few months i have to regenerate the key and i think this is what has happened, beacuse it is not showing products on the live server

Comment: ok the key was not the problem, and the live server using all the same info shows products and no error